# how to make ROS to work on a microcontroller like PIC24

Tags: ros, microcontroller, installation, rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am doing research on CubeSat (a small satellite) It contains PIC24 microcontroller, so I want to know that can we install ROS in a microcontroller like other RTOS.
If we can install please guide me how to make it or what are the prime requirements??

I am completely new to this field please provide information from basic, I feel its complicated.

---

Thanks & Regards
Rama K Ande

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31081/how-to-make-ros-to-work-on-a-microcontroller-like-pic24/) by [raan10](https://answers.ros.org/users/2113/raan10/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-04-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-04-19**:
Yes it is complicated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes it is complicated :)

I am not sure a PIC24 can run linux and then ROS on top of it. I don't think this is possible. Even if it is, I personally haven't heard anyone talk about it. Take a look [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Introduction) and [here](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html) to see if you can meet the hardware requirements.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-04-30**:
The hardware requirements are also very dependent on what functionality you want to get out of ROS.  If you want to run a GL accelerated simulation that won't work.  If you want to do basic IO it will be much easier.